# Sony Vaio S Auto Dimming won't stop

Tags: display, sony-vaio

the Auto dimming feature just doesn't stop.
I've tried many methods but they just won't work. 
Especially in advanced power settings, the line which supposedly stops auto dimming isn't present for me

Answer (score 1):

On my Vaio (SVS1511C5E), upgraded to Windows 8, you can disable auto-brightness, which does not seem to work properly after the upgrade, in the Image Quality section of the Vaio Control Center, not in Power & Battery nor in the Windows Power Options.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you dont have the proper drivers installed.  Check the Sony website for the proper drivers for the OS installed on your Vaio.  If you installed an unsupported Windows OS on your Vaio, you can try the other Windows drivers, they *may* work.

If that is unsuccessful, or your are running a non-Windows OS, you might also be able to disable the dimmer in BIOS.  Check your Vaio's user manual on how to access the BIOS if you dont know how.